# SharePoint 2007 HttpHandler can't use SPContext.Current.Site or SPContext.Current.Web when called from jQuery

Tags: 2007, jquery

I have the need to develop a custom HttpHandler in SharePoint. To start, I just coded up a simple example [from here](http://pastebin.com/HXLjR2xT). On line 35 or 36 of that code I get a NullReferenceException thrown if I call my HttpHander page from jQuery. But if I call the page directly in my browser, I get the results I expect. I have seen some examples online for building an HttpHandler in SharePoint and calling it from jQuery and they don't seem to really do anything differently then I am. Ex: [Sharepoint list and linq using jquery and ihttphandler](http://bobbybeckner.com/index.php/sharepoint-list-and-linq-using-jquery-and-ihttphandler/)

Any ideas on why I can't seem to get the Current context from SPContext when I am calling from jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was a really dumb mistake on my part, it actually turns out that I was requesting the wrong path in my jQuery ajax call. I was requesting url: `"_layouts/MyStuff/MyHandler.ashx"` which was trying to request `"/Pages/_layouts/MyStuff/MyHandler.ashx"` instead of `"/_layouts/MyStuff/MyHandler.ashx"`. So, changing to the right path solved my problem. Boy don't I feel dumb now!.